# Ordering by sorted items from joined table in mysql

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlalchemy

I have 2 tables (User, Order) in mysql with 1-n relationship b/w them where a user can have multiple orders.

So in order to fetch orders for each user I do a join b/w two tables like below

```
select user.id, order.item_name from user join `order` on user.id = order.user_id;
```

Here is the minimal sql with insert statements to reproduce this

```sql
CREATE TABLE `user` (
      `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
       `user_name` varchar(96) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) 
    
CREATE TABLE `order` (
      `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `user_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
      `item_name` varchar(96) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
      KEY `ix_order_user_id` (`user_id`),
      CONSTRAINT `order_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
    )
```

Here are the inserts

```sql
INSERT into user(user_name)
    values ('user1'),
           ('user2'),
           ('user3'),
           ('user4'),
           ('user5'),
           ('user6'),
           ('user7');
          
INSERT into `order` (user_id, item_name) values ((select id from user where user.user_name = 'user1'), "apple");
INSERT into `order` (user_id, item_name) values ((select id from user where user.user_name = 'user1'), "banana");
INSERT into `order` (user_id, item_name) values ((select id from user where user.user_name = 'user1'), "orange");

INSERT into `order` (user_id, item_name) values ((select id from user where user.user_name = 'user2'), "apple");
INSERT into `order` (user_id, item_name) values ((select id from user where user.user_name = 'user2'), "orange");

INSERT into `order` (user_id, item_name) values ((select id from user where user.user_name = 'user3'), "apple");
INSERT into `order` (user_id, item_name) values ((select id from user where user.user_name = 'user3'), "banana");

INSERT into `order` (user_id, item_name) values ((select id from user where user.user_name = 'user4'), "apple");

INSERT into `order` (user_id, item_name) values ((select id from user where user.user_name = 'user5'), "orange");

INSERT into `order` (user_id, item_name) values ((select id from user where user.user_name = 'user6'), "banana");

INSERT into `order` (user_id, item_name) values ((select id from user where user.user_name = 'user7'), "banana");
INSERT into `order` (user_id, item_name) values ((select id from user where user.user_name = 'user7'), "grapes");
```

So the  data set I have after above inserts is this

```
Items for user1 = ["apples", "oranges", "bananas"]
Items for user2 = ["apples", "oranges"]
Items for user3 = ["apples", "bananas"]
Items for user4 = ["apples"]
Items for user5 = ["oranges"]
Items for user6 = ["bananas"]
Items for user7 = ["bananas", "grapes"]
```

So the result set that I want from User table should be ordered like below

```
user4    # ["apples"]
user3    # ["apples", "bananas"]
user1    # ["apples", "oranges", "bananas"]
user2    # ["apples", "oranges"]
user6    # ["bananas"]
user7    # ["bananas", "grapes"]
user5    # ["oranges"]
```

Here is a simple demonstration of why the above ordering is correct

```
d = dict(user1=["apples", "oranges", "bananas"], user2=["apples", "oranges"], user3=["apples", "bananas"], user4=["apples"], user5=["oranges"], user6=["bananas"], user7=["bananas", "grapes"])

# User ordering without sorting item_names
 
for i in sorted(d, key=lambda k: d[k]):
    print(f"{i}: {d[i]}")
    
user4: ['apples']
user3: ['apples', 'bananas']
user2: ['apples', 'oranges']
user1: ['apples', 'oranges', 'bananas']
user6: ['bananas']
user7: ['bananas', 'grapes']
user5: ['oranges']

# User ordering with sorted item_names

for i in sorted(d, key=lambda k: sorted(d[k])):
    print(f"{i}: {d[i]}")
    
user4: ['apples']
user3: ['apples', 'bananas']
user1: ['apples', 'oranges', 'bananas']
user2: ['apples', 'oranges']
user6: ['bananas']
user7: ['bananas', 'grapes']
user5: ['oranges']
```

But I get the result in following when I join two tables and order by `Order.item_name`

```py
for i in session.query(User).join(Order).order_by(Order.item_name).all():
    items = [o.item_name for o in i.orders]
    print(i.user_name, items)

# Result
user1 ['apple', 'orange', 'banana']
user3 ['banana', 'apple']
user4 ['apple']
user6 ['banana']
user7 ['banana', 'grapes']
user2 ['orange']
user5 ['orange']
```

So is there any way to achieve this with raw sql & with SQLAlchemy ?

Comment: Add according ORDER BY to your SQL text which orders the rows by `FIND_IN_SET({user's fruit}, {CSV with fruits order for this user}`).

Comment: @Akina can you please help with query syntax ?

Comment: Provide complete sample as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO and desired output for this data. The best way - create online fiddle. See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) *Now I want to order results from my main User table based on the sorted item names each user have, consider the following data set* Does this set is present in some MySQL table? If so then add it to fiddle.

Comment: Added the schema and inserts for minimal reconstruction.

Comment: I want to have user rows ordered by sorted list of their item names. If I simply order user table by Order.item_name then the ordering will not be correct since their each user can contain multiple items and if the items themselves are not sorted, the users will not be ordered correctly.

Comment: *I want to have user rows ordered by sorted list of their item names.* Unclear. The table is a heap. There is no relative rows ordering in it.  PS. Does the elements ordering in the output JSON array makes sense for you?

Comment: `user1    # ["apples", "oranges", "bananas"]` - explain in details what sets this fruits ordering. If it is *`d = dict( ...`* then this data array must be stored in one more MySQL table.

Comment: I updated the question, to show a demonstration of ordering set by default Python sorting algorithm.

Comment: o_O Do you want python to perform the subtask which should be performed on the database side?

Comment: That was just a demonstration of what correct ordering should look like and not meant to perform DB task at Python layer.

Comment: *That was just a demonstration of what correct ordering should look like* You must not only show this but explain where this "correct ordering" is taken from.

Comment: Well that correct ordering is taken from python's sorting algorithm, don't know what else i can explain here.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT user.user_name,
       JSON_ARRAYAGG(`order`.item_name) items_list
FROM user
JOIN `order` ON user.id = `order`.user_id
GROUP BY user.user_name
ORDER BY GROUP_CONCAT(`order`.item_name);
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=886c836d4f8ea946e6ba5a644f21032f

CAST is added because the fiddle prints JSON column values in HEX codes, like binary data.